# How to disable refresh from php after subit a form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I got this code in html, js and php, which when a selection option `#eassociado` is clicked, it redirect to `#chkveg` page. But when i submit the form, the page seens like refresh and the email was subimitted but the button dont redirect to the page.

The only way i tryed to make this was removing the `e.preventDefault`, but the the form dont submit with it.

html

```
  <form id="formulario" action="<? $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="POST"> 
<select id="eassociado" name="eassociado" >
         <option disabled selected value> -- Selecione uma opção -- </option>
          <option class="lista">ABRAPP</option>
          <option class="lista">ABAAI</option>
          <option class="lista">IBGC</option>
          <option class="lista">ABRACAM</option>
          <option class="lista">ABBC</option>
          <option class="aAncord">Associados Ancord</option>
          <option class="naoLista">Não Associados</option>
         </select>

    <select name="ingresso" id="chkveg" >
                <option value="https://pag.ae/7ULKPL7TH">Associados Ancord + C.Dados = R$700,00</option>
                <option value="https://pag.ae/7ULKQ8Zm2">Associados Ancord Normal = R$800,00</option>
                <option value="https://pag.ae/7UTdp8_CG">Associados Entidades Apoiadoras + C.Dados = R$875,00</option>
                <option value="https://pag.ae/7UTdpwWem">Associados Entidades Apoiadoras Normal = R$1.000,00</option>
                <option value="https://pag.ae/7UTdpPZjn">Não Associados + C.Dados = R$1.100,00</option>
                <option value="https://pag.ae/7UTdq2JsG">Não Associados Normal = R$1.250,00</option>
                </select>

    <button name="envia" id="btnget" class="submit-btn" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Js

```
var ingressoBloco = document.getElementById('ingresso-bloco');
var eassociado = document.getElementById('eassociado');
var chkveg = document.getElementById('chkveg');

chkveg.style.display = 'none';
ingressoBloco.style.display = 'none';

eassociado.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var escolhido = eassociado.options[eassociado.selectedIndex].index;


  if(escolhido == 1) {
    chkveg.style.display = 'inline-block';
    ingressoBloco.style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[0].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[1].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[2].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[3].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[4].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[5].style.display = 'none';



            $(document).ready(function() {


                $(document).on('click', '#btnget', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                    let formValido = document.getElementById("formulario").checkValidity();

                    if (formValido) {
                        $(location).attr('href', $('#chkveg').val())
                    }

                });

});
  }
   else if(escolhido == 2) {
    chkveg.style.display = 'inline-block';
    ingressoBloco.style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.selectedIndex = 2;
    chkveg.options[0].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[1].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[2].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[3].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[4].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[5].style.display = 'none';

                $(document).ready(function() {


                $(document).on('click', '#btnget', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                    let formValido = document.getElementById("formulario").checkValidity();

                    if (formValido) {
                        $(location).attr('href', $('#chkveg').val())
                    }

                });

  } // Asssim por diante
   else if(escolhido == 3) {
    chkveg.style.display = 'inline-block';
    ingressoBloco.style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.selectedIndex = 2;
    chkveg.options[0].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[1].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[2].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[3].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[4].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[5].style.display = 'none';

        $(document).ready(function() {


                $(document).on('click', '#btnget', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                    let formValido = document.getElementById("formulario").checkValidity();

                    if (formValido) {
                        $(location).attr('href', $('#chkveg').val())
                    }

                });

  } // Asssim por diante
   else if(escolhido == 4) {
    chkveg.style.display = 'inline-block';
    ingressoBloco.style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.selectedIndex = 2;
    chkveg.options[0].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[1].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[2].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[3].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[4].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[5].style.display = 'none';

        $(document).ready(function() {


                $(document).on('click', '#btnget', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                    let formValido = document.getElementById("formulario").checkValidity();

                    if (formValido) {
                        $(location).attr('href', $('#chkveg').val())
                    }

                });

  } // Asssim por diante
   else if(escolhido == 5) {
    chkveg.style.display = 'inline-block';
    ingressoBloco.style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.selectedIndex = 2;
    chkveg.options[0].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[1].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[2].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[3].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[4].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[5].style.display = 'none';

        $(document).ready(function() {


                $(document).on('click', '#btnget', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                    let formValido = document.getElementById("formulario").checkValidity();

                    if (formValido) {
                        $(location).attr('href', $('#chkveg').val())
                    }

                });

  } // Asssim por diante
  else if(escolhido == 6) {
    chkveg.style.display = 'inline-block';
    ingressoBloco.style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.selectedIndex = 0;
    chkveg.options[0].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[1].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[2].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[3].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[4].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[5].style.display = 'none';

        $(document).ready(function() {


                $(document).on('click', '#btnget', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                    let formValido = document.getElementById("formulario").checkValidity();

                    if (formValido) {
                        $(location).attr('href', $('#chkveg').val())
                    }

                });

  } // Asssim por diante
    else if(escolhido == 7) {
    chkveg.style.display = 'inline-block';
    ingressoBloco.style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.selectedIndex = 4;
    chkveg.options[0].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[1].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[2].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[3].style.display = 'none';
    chkveg.options[4].style.display = 'inline-block';
    chkveg.options[5].style.display = 'inline-block';

        $(document).ready(function() {


                $(document).on('click', '#btnget', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                    let formValido = document.getElementById("formulario").checkValidity();

                    if (formValido) {
                        $(location).attr('href', $('#chkveg').val())
                    }

                });

  } // Asssim por diante



});
```

php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['envia'])) {

 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
 $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
 $nascimento = $_POST['nascimento'];
 $celular = $_POST['celular'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
 $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
 $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
 $numero = $_POST['numero'];
 $complemento = $_POST['complemento'];
 $bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
 $estado = $_POST['estado'];
 $corretoradevalores = $_POST['corretoradevalores'];
 $corretoradecambio = $_POST['corretoradecambio'];
 $banco = $_POST['banco'];
 $estado = $_POST['estado'];
 $cracha = $_POST['cracha'];
 $empresacracha = $_POST['empresacracha'];
 $ingresso = $_POST['ingresso'];
 $comosoube = $_POST['comosoube'];
 $eassociado = $_POST['eassociado'];
 $setordaempresa = $_POST['setordaempresa'];

    //====================================================

    //REMETENTE --> ESTE EMAIL TEM QUE SER VALIDO DO DOMINIO
    //==================================================== 
    $email_remetente = "contato@congressoprotecaodados.com.br"; // deve ser uma conta de email do seu dominio 
    //====================================================

    //Configurações do email, ajustar conforme necessidade
    //==================================================== 
    $email_destinatario = "lmorato@gmail.com"; // pode ser qualquer email que receberá as mensagens
    $email_reply = "$email"; 
    $email_assunto = "Inscrição 1º Congresso Proteção de dados"; // Este será o assunto da mensagem
    //====================================================

    //Monta o Corpo da Mensagem
    //====================================================

         $email_conteudo = "Nome = $nome \n"; 
         $email_conteudo .= "Cpf = $cpf \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "Data de Nascimento = $nascimento \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "Celular = $celular \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "Email = $email \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "Cargo = $cargo \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "Empresa = $empresa \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "Endereço = $endereco \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "Número = $numero \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "Complemento = $complemento \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "Bairro = $bairro \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "Estado = $estado \n";


         $email_conteudo .= "Nome da empresa para crachá = $empresacracha \n";

         $email_conteudo .= "Setor da empresa = $setordaempresa \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "Como Soube = $comosoube \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "É associado = $eassociado \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "Tipo do ingresso = $ingresso \n";




    //====================================================

    //Seta os Headers (Alterar somente caso necessario) 
    //==================================================== 
    $email_headers = implode ( "\n",array ( "From: $email_remetente", "Reply-To: $email_reply", "Return-Path: $email_remetente","MIME-Version: 1.0","X-Priority: 3","Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" ) );
    //====================================================

    //Enviando o email 
    //==================================================== 
    (mail ($email_destinatario, $email_assunto, nl2br($email_conteudo), $email_headers));
    //====================================================
} 
?>
```

Comment: Where is the FORM in your html ?

Comment: i forgot to put the html form tag, updated

Comment: @Chead Did you try `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`? Or maybe, listen on the `submit` event and not on the `click` event! What you want to prevent is the submission of the form.

Comment: @sjahan i will try it

Comment: @sjahan that not worked :(